# Subset dataframe by unique values within a column in R

Tags: r, dplyr

Hello I have a dataframe such as

```
Group COL1 Event 
G1 SP1  1
G1 SP2  1
G1 SP3  2
G1 SP3  2 
G2 SP4  3
G2 SP7  3
G2 SP5  6
G3 SP1  1 
G4 SP1  6
```

And I want to keep only COL1 if `Event` is unique (so here for exemple SP3 and SP5 are unique within the column Event).

Then I should get :

```
Group COL1 Event 
G1 SP3  2
G1 SP3  2 
G2 SP5  6 
G3 SP1  1 
G4 SP1  6
```

`SP1` and `SP2` were 2 in column `Event1` so they do not pass

`SP4` and `SP7` were 2 in column `Event3` so they do not pass

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use data.table to group by `Group` and `Event` and only return the group contents (`.SD`) if the number of unique COL1 values (`uniqueN(COL1)`) is 1.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[, if(uniqueN(COL1) == 1) .SD, by = .(Group, Event)]
#    Group Event COL1
# 1:    G1     2  SP3
# 2:    G1     2  SP3
# 3:    G2     6  SP5
# 4:    G3     1  SP1
# 5:    G4     6  SP1
```

Data used:

```
df <- fread('
Group COL1 Event 
G1 SP1  1
G1 SP2  1
G1 SP3  2
G1 SP3  2 
G2 SP4  3
G2 SP7  3
G2 SP5  6
G3 SP1  1 
G4 SP1  6  
')
```

Comment: Hello, thank you but I need to take into account the group level as well (see the edit where Event number can be in different groups)

Answer (score 2):

An option with `base R` using `ave`

```
subset(df, ave(COL1, Group, Event,
      FUN = function(x) length(unique(x))) == 1)
#  Group COL1 Event
#3    G1  SP3     2
#4    G1  SP3     2
#7    G2  SP5     6
#8    G3  SP1     1
#9    G4  SP1     6
```

Answer (score 1):

Another `data.table` option

```
> setDT(df)[,.SD[uniqueN(COL1)==1],.(Group,Event)]
   Group Event COL1
1:    G1     2  SP3
2:    G1     2  SP3
3:    G2     6  SP5
4:    G3     1  SP1
5:    G4     6  SP1
```